# How can I group equal values and print the minimum and maximum parameters with Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, max, min

I have this input data:

```
miRNA17 dvex571195  207 230
miRNA17 dvex571195  189 229
miRNA17 dvex571195  207 241
miRNA17 dvex571195  207 230
miRNA17 dvex571195  80  111
miRNA18 dvex449276  12  43
miRNA18 dvex196735  2909    2929
miRNA18 dvex765590  183 213
miRNA22 dvex826214  206 236
miRNA23 dvex529006  111 168
miRNA24 dvex803612  317 347
```

I want to group the rows with the same First and Second value. Next, with this 'groups' I need to print in the third column the minimum value of the 'group' and in the fourth column print the maximum value of the 'group'. The output will be:

```
miRNA17 dvex571195  80  241
miRNA18 dvex449276  12  43
miRNA18 dvex196735  2909    2929
miRNA18 dvex765590  183 213
miRNA22 dvex826214  206 236
miRNA23 dvex529006  111 168
miRNA24 dvex803612  317 347
```

I tried to group all data in a big %Hash, and my key are represent by the first and the second columns. But I can use a method to organize the subsequents columns. The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %lines; # hash with 1rd and 2th elements as key
my %first_line_per_group; # stores in which line a group appeared first
while(my $line = <>) {
# remove line break
chomp $line;

# retrieve elements form line
my @elements = split /\s+/, $line;

# build key from elements 1 and 2 (array 0-based!)
my $key = $elements[0]." ".$elements[1];

if(! $lines{key}) {
    #my $min = max $elements[3];
    $first_line_per_group{$key} = $elements[0]."\t".$elements[1];#."\t".$min;
}
push @{ $lines{$key} }, $line;

}

# the result:
 for my $key (keys %lines) {
    print $first_line_per_group{$key}."\t";
    print "$_\n" for @{ $lines{$key} };
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
miRNA17 dvex571195  miRNA17 dvex571195 207 230
miRNA17 dvex571195 189 229
miRNA17 dvex571195 207 241
miRNA17 dvex571195 207 230
miRNA17 dvex571195 80 111
miRNA18 dvex449276  miRNA18 dvex449276 12   43
miRNA18 dvex196735  miRNA18 dvex196735 2909 2929
miRNA18 dvex765590  miRNA18 dvex765590 183  213
miRNA22 dvex826214  miRNA22 dvex826214 206  236
miRNA23 dvex529006  miRNA23 dvex529006 111  168
miRNA24 dvex803612  miRNA24 dvex803612 317  347
```

But I need to eliminate the grouped values and do the work above described.

Comment: your desired output preserves order by first line; is that intentional, or would sorting it be acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only missing one thing: When `$lines{key}` is true, you want to adjust the `$first_line_per_group{$key}` so that its value contains the group's min and max.

After some cleanup, you end up with the following code:

```
my %groups;
while (<>) {
   my @f = split;
   my $key = "$f[0] $f[1]";

   if ($groups{$key}) {
      $f[2] = $groups{key}[2] if $groups{key}[2] < $f[2];
      $f[3] = $groups{key}[3] if $groups{key}[3] > $f[3];
   }

   $groups{$key} = \@f;
}

for my $key (keys(%groups)) {
   print(join(' ', @{ $groups{$key} }), "\n");
}
```

Comment: What do you refer with 'after some cleanup'?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe the small edit I've just made helps?

Comment: Finally I understand. The solution is great. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this program, which seems to do what you need.

I'm not clear whether your file is tab-separated or just whitespace-separated, but as long as there are no spaces in the values it doesn't matter. I have split each record on whitespace, as that is what your code does.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/ min max /;

my %data;

while (<>) {
  my @fields = split;
  push @{ $data{"@fields[0,1]"} }, [ @fields[2,3] ];
}

for my $key (sort keys %data) {
  my $val = $data{$key};
  print join(' ', $key, min(map $_->[0], @$val), max(map $_->[1], @$val)), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
miRNA17 dvex571195 80 241
miRNA18 dvex196735 2909 2929
miRNA18 dvex449276 12 43
miRNA18 dvex765590 183 213
miRNA22 dvex826214 206 236
miRNA23 dvex529006 111 168
miRNA24 dvex803612 317 347
```